# How to ask CompletableFuture use non-daemon threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, daemon, future, completable-future

I have wrote following code:

```
 System.out.println("Main thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
 CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
     try {
         System.out.println("Before sleep thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId(), + " isDaemon:" + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
          Thread.sleep(100);
          System.out.println("After sleep");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  });
  future.whenComplete((r, e) -> System.out.println("whenCompleted thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()));
```

and this one prints:

```
Main thread:1
Before sleep thread:11 isDaemon:true
```

and finishes.

How can I change this behaviour?

**P.S.** I don't see anything related in `runAsync` java doc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-) for `runAsync()` says:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() after it runs the given action.

There is *another* version of `runAsync()` where you can **pass** an ExecutorService.

Thus: when the default [commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) doesn't do what you want - then create your own ExecutorService instead.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

to the main method after running your future. I'll block until all tasks in the pool have been completed.

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Comment: after or before?

Comment: After. I've put it in the last line of the `main` method.